# Finding EDT time in java

Tags: java, time, timezone

How to get the EDT time in java. I always get the GMT time when i use new Date() method. Can anyone guide me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York")).getTime()`